# Connection between pip and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

In my Linux system I have python 2.x , 3.5 and 3.8. (This question is about python3.x)

When I use the command python3 it starts python 3.8
and the command python3.5 starts python 3.5

I can see 3 pip commands, pip(for python 2.x) and pip3, pip3.8 (both for python 3.8)

How can I install packages only for python 3.5

Comment: Try `python3.5 -m pip install <package>`. It requires, of course, that `pip` is installed for `python3.5`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to install pip for python3.5 ? I don't think its pre-installed

Comment: Simply follow https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#get-pip-py, but replace `python` with `python3.5`

Comment: `python3.5 -m ensurepip` should work too https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html

Comment: Your question has way too few details for anyone to tell you anything meaningful; and then it will probably be a duplicate. Which OS, how were these Python versions installed, where?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+different+Python+versions